# How many objects iterable in a vector before L3 cache misses occur?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu, shared-ptr, cpu-architecture

Lets say I have an class which contains data members with heap-allocated memory:

```
class X{
    std::map<int, double> a;
    std::set<int> b;
    std::vector<int>;
    std::string c;
}
```

and I have a `std::vector<shared_ptr<X>>` containing many of these `X` objects, which I will iterate through and access the map.begin():

```
for(int i =0; i<vec.size(); i++){
    running_total += *(vec[i]->a.begin());
}
```

Theoretically how many objects should I be able to hold/iterate through in the vector before I encounter L3 cache misses?

I thought the answer would be how many cache lines per object the L3 cache could hold, but  L3 size/sizeof(x_element.get()) doesn't seem to be giving me the answer I am seeing from profiling....

My L3 cache is 8MB, each cache line is 64 bytes and therefore I could hold about 125,000 objects before L3 cache misses. However I am seeing L3 cache misses at much fewer numbers of vector elements.

Comment: In theory? **0**. You will always miss the first time you use the memory.

Comment: How distinct is your timing difference between L3 cache hit and main memory hit? They should be fairly close, while the difference between L2 (~256kiB quite often) and L3 is frequently proportionately larger.

Comment: Also, your terminology is off. Usually "DRAM miss" would imply a page fault/hitting swap, while a "cache miss" means having to go to main memory because there wasn't a match/hit in the cache.

Comment: unless your process has exclusive access to the CPU, I'd imagine L3 will get populated with stuff from other programs...

Comment: You're also following several pointer indirections in order to access the data. These are likely to be scattered around memory and cause plenty of cache misses.

Comment: @Jeff "how often CPU was stalled on the main memory (DRAM)", which I take to be the same as time spent on an L3 cache miss?

Comment: @RedAlert you raise a good point that L3 is almost universally shared across cores.

Comment: valgrind --tool=cachegrind will tell you

Comment: I guess that your profiling tool is telling you that you have one L3 cache miss for each memory page that contains data from any of the several levels of indirection that has not already been loaded into L3.

Comment: The number of objects that you can hold in L3 will depend on the memory allocation pattern of the objects across the memory space and on the size of the pages in L3. The theoretical maximum might be with contiguous sequential allocation. The minimum would probably be if you would find a way to allocate 1 instance only in each memory page.

Comment: We have one cache line for the smart pointer, another cache line for the pointer to a, another cache line for the std::map data- so thats 3x 64 bytes per object? Is this thinking correct?

Comment: Close I think. 1/8th of a line for each `vector<shared_ptr<X>>` element, 1 for each `X` and the locally stored `begin()` pointer in the `map`, and 1 for the actual first element data = 2.125 cache lines per top-level vector element access. Again, you will very likely have last-level cache aliasing-induced misses unless you very carefully control your map element allocations, use large contiguous physical memory mappings, etc.

Comment: @Jeff and thats the (theoretical) worst-case isnt it? You assume the data all lies in different cache lines etc.

Comment: @user997112 I don't see it the best/average cases being much better. `sizeof(X)` for this contrived case is already 2 cache lines, so that's not going to be shared. If `X::a`'s elements really are `int32_t`/`double` pairs, you are neighboring half a cache line there, not counting allocator overhead.

Comment: @user997112 Also, if you are using a relatively recent CPU, you could probably get substantial speedup by having a cached "begin" element in `X`; hardware prefetchers are pretty quick to notice strongly linear access patterns even with multi-line strides, and you could avoid all the headache of skipping around random heap locations.

Comment: @Jeff if X was the child class in part of an inheritance hierarchy, would there be an additional cache line required for the base class pointer (because the child class is an offset to this)?

Comment: @user997112 No, for the loop you show, only `X::a.begin()`'s pointer is being touched, which is at a statically known offset for all cases of non-virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Intel CPUs you can use [Intel Architecture Code Analyzer (IACA)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) for analyzing your loop. If I remember correctly it can also analyze cache misses if you configure it properly, etc.

Another tool is Valgrind which is a simulator which can also be used to simulate cache behaviour if you configure it correctly.

But in general - to maximize the cache usage - you should separate out the data that you iterate over in one linear array (and as small as possible). E.g. one array with keys (or data you iterate over) and one array with the rest if possible. So in short the cache really kicks in only if the addresses of the data you iterate over is ordered linearly and NOT random access as you will get if you iterate over many objects allocated on different places on the heap.